# MVVM: True seperation between GUI and ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I'm looking for a good example/way of a **TRUE** seperation between MVVM View and ViewModel. I don't even want 1 reference in the View to the ViewModel or the other way around.

---

**Description of the problem**

Just to visuallise my problem:
Imagine 3 seperate projects; GUI(Views), Logic(ViewModels) and Model.

Overview:

[image]

How do I set up the solution, so it won't result in circle references?

**Approach**

One thought of mine was to use a 4th project as some kind of broker:

[image]

What I don't like about it, is that the Logic(ViewModel) project would be the main project in this case. Or maybe it's ok and I just have weird feelings.

What do you guys think?

---

**Edit**

Thanks to Charles Mager I've found a very interesting article, in which a mapping is predefined and so when he calls the ShowDialog method it decides based on the mapping which UI to load.
[CodeProject: Showing Dialogs When Using the MVVM Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern)

Comment: I added your first image, but your second one appears to be identical - do you want to check it?

Comment: thanks and yes there went something wrong. I replaced the second link, so it should now point to the right picture.

Comment: One of the best and easiest ways to do this is to use a dependency injection container (like Unity) and only reference things via an interface. So your view would have a property called `IViewModel ViewModel {get;set;}`, and it would populate that property by resolving the interface from the DI container.

Comment: Ok I will have a look at that, thx!

Comment: Who says your view can't know about your VM?  That doesn't make any sense, as it *has* to bind against properties of the VM.

Comment: not the way I was teached to use MVVM. Of course you have binding properties, but that doesn't mean the View knows the VM. It just knows some properties that the VM can implement, but doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't one a single reference between the View and ViewModel, then why is your ViewModels project trying to reference the Views project?

Your image implies this is to allow showing dialogs.  What you'd usually do in this situation is define an interface in your ViewModels project that has a method `ShowDialog(object viewModel)` - call it `IDialogService` or something.

You would then have a 4th *bootstrapper* project that would take care of starting the app, showing the Main Window and would implement this `IDialogService`, mapping the ViewModel to the View and showing it.

Comment: exactly, to show Dialogs and other Views..

sounds just like what I'm looking for and with the IDialogService kewword I found some example projects. 
Thank you!


PS: Sry, I can't upvote your answer neither do other action to show that this was useful. Again because of the lack of reputation points ...

Answer (score 1):

VM knowing about the View is much more questionable, and you should probably avoid it. You might want to implement the dialog functionality in your View project. Just because it's logic doesn't mean the VM should be in charge of it. If you have the viewmodel imperatively executing methods like `ShowDialog()` then you should probably refactor the VM and pull the `ShowDialog()` method call into the View library. If you must trigger it with the VM, define method delegates on the ViewModel for it to trigger, but assign `ShowDialog()` to that delegate in the View layer.

Comment: in the version I implemented now, there is this service which knows which viewmodel belongs to which view. So when another (the main) project starts the app and creates the VM, it passes the service interface in the constructor. Now the VM can call the show dialog function without knowing anything about the view. The service decides depending on the passed viewmodel which view it has to show.

Comment: @HansVader it sounds like you have decided on a pattern already, but for the record I would like to say that you might have difficulty with organization and code maintenance. Having the ViewModel call a method named `ShowDialog()` is an implicit coupling of your GUI to your ViewModel, because your ViewModel understands the concept of a dialog, which should really be limited to the View. I think it would be better to have an event on your ViewModel that the ViewModel fires, but the View assigns the `ShowDialog()` method call to the event. Here's a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dCMumi

Comment: yeah I already encountered a problem like this when I created the login mask. Because I want to switch to a register UI, but the VM shouldn't know if it's just a UserControl or a Dialog... I will probably implement something like your suggestion with events. Thx!

Comment: but how do you manage the View then? Cause the view fires a Command e.g. 'ShowHelpDialog' which is defined in the viewmodel. So how to avoid the VM knowing it's a Dialog/UI?

Comment: @HansVader It may only be a problem with the name of the command. Instead of naming the command in relation to the UI, name it in relation to what's happening in the VM. In my fiddle, that's an event called `AfterDataFetched`. Even though the end result is the same, that the dialog is shown after the data is fetched, the VM doesn't know anything except that it's firing the `AfterDataFetched` event after the data is fetched. It's the View's responsibility to define what happens in the event, which allows for clean separation. And, you now can do more than just dialog stuff with that command.

Comment: @HansVader I looked at the codeproject article you linked, and I tend to disagree with the statement that all logic should be in the ViewModel. Note that the author even states that it's their interpretation of MVVM. If all of the UI logic and Views are managed declaratively, and all imperative and business logic is in the ViewModel, I might agree. But if you are dealing with an imperative UI, which it appears you are, then you need to separate View and ViewModel by UI logic versus business/application-level logic.

Comment: @ moarboilerplate Interesting thought. I will give it a try in my implementation or at least remove/avoid the imperative UI part.